# How I can get attribute of a Web Element in a list?

Tags: java, list, selenium

[PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byfac.jpg)

I am getting error on the getAttribute() saying cant resolve method. this method usually works with WebElement objects but some reason this is not. This is the code also check the picture.

```
public void radioButtonUsingLable(String lablename) {

    List<WebElement> radio = brower.findElements(By.xpath("//label[text() = 
            \"" + lablename + ":\"]/following-sibling::div[1]//child::input"));

    for (WebElement element: radio) {
        element.click();
        delay(2000);
    }
}


@Test
public void test1(){
    radioButtonUsingLable("Radio Button");

    List<WebElement> radio = brower.findElements(By.xpath("//label[text() = 
            \"Radio Button:\"]/following-sibling::div[1]//child::input"));

    for (WebElement element: radio) {
        String checked = radio.getAttribute("checked");
        boolean isSelected = checked != null  && 
        checked.contentEquals("true") ? true : false;
        Assert.assertTrue(isSelected);
    }
}
```

Comment: @nafeez007 - normally we don't recommend you attach photos of things - just include the information in your question. However, in this case I'm glad you did because it helped me to identify the problem faster.

Comment: if you had provided more information about exception stack trace and your html dom structure. that would be nice to identify even faster.
That true getAttribute() is in RED identify easily

Comment: There wouldn't have been a stack trace since the code didn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you see something like that (shown in OP's photo as red underline for method name), it could mean that the object type you think you have is in fact not.

In your code, `radio` is actually a list. `element` is an element in that list. You should have:

```
for (WebElement element: radio) {
    String checked = element.getAttribute("checked");  // change radio to element here
    boolean isSelected = checked != null  && 
            checked.contentEquals("true") ? true : false;
    Assert.assertTrue(isSelected);
}
```

To help solve this in future, think about choosing better variable names. For example, if you have a list of things, make the variable plural. In this case, it would have given you a clue that you couldn't call `getAttribute()` on a variable called `radioButtons` or `radioButtonsList`.

Remember, sometimes the best documentation you can have is clean code.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Silly mistake on my part